# Vertically center all contents inside jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I horizontally and vertically center all the contents of a jumbotron in bootstrap 3? I have just started learning it.

The following is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="site-wrapper">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p id="subHeader"><small>sub header</small></p>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 lefty">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
}
.site-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-top: 5px solid #5A332B;
}
.jumbotron {
    background-color: #ccbb99 !important;
    /*background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9));*/
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.lefty {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform: translateY` to vertical align the content like this..

```
.centerme {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/MlRejPA7m2

Use `text-center` to horizontal align

Answer (score -1):

use the CSS code to achieve this:

```
.jumbotron{disply:flex;
align-content:center;
justify-items:center;
align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: use flex-direction:column

Comment: without using flex-direction:coloumn, everything comes to the center but they are horizontal. If flex-coloumn is used then no changes occurs.

Comment: please use column instead of coloumn

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my comment, I have used `column` but then no changes occur and by no changes I mean the content doesnt come to the center.